# How to enable the input and button from parent component in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

I am having parent component with the following,

**app.component.html:**

```
<h1> Look at console </h1>
<app-profile-image></app-profile-image>
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
  ngOnInit() {

    console.log((document.getElementById('fileInput') as any));

    console.log((document.getElementById('fileInput') as any).disabled);

    console.log((document.getElementsByClassName('hover-text') as any));

    console.log((document.getElementsByClassName('hover-text') as any)[0].disabled)
  }
```

You could able to see the parent and child component implementation in the **example** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-zaipvg

Here in child component you could able to see the following,

```
  <button class="hover-text" [disabled]="true">Choose file</button>
```

and

```
<input id="fileInput" type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)" [disabled]="true">
```

Both of it is in disabled state at default..

The thing i am trying to do is **need to enable these two disabled attributes using parent**.

The child `<app-profile-image></app-profile-image>` which i am using is library in my real application which means i cannot directly change the code of the child so via parent i need to change the `disabled` attribute to get enabled..

**I have tried,**

```
console.log((document.getElementById('fileInput') as any));
```

and

```
console.log((document.getElementsByClassName('hover-text') as any));
```

and both gives disabled attribute (you can see the console in the given example)

But,

```
console.log((document.getElementById('fileInput') as any).disabled);
```

and

```
console.log((document.getElementsByClassName('hover-text') as any)[0].disabled)
```

gives the result as false but i am getting the disabled attribute in the above given console.log but then why i am getting the false as result even though the attribute was present?

If it gives the result as `true` then it is known that disabled is true so based on the condition i can enable the button and input but don't know the reason it gives disabled as false in the console..

Kindly help me to enable both the disabled `button` and `input` in the [given example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-zaipvg) using **only parent component** (which is `app.component.ts` ) so that i can choose any image to upload in it..

No way i can edit the child component because it is a library package and i am not having any code in my real application and only thing i can do is i can edit the parent component alone..

Comment: create global variable and get data from `@Output` and assign then to variable. variable value is in true and false. replace them to `[disabled]="variable"`

Comment: I edited your stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-wrdumr

Comment: @Florian, What edit you have made?? I could able to see only the result and not the code that you have changed.. Even though the output is itself like what i have given..

Comment: @Abhishek, I cannot edit anything in child because its another library and i have installed via ```npm install fileupload```..

Comment: @HelloWorld I didn't change in child, but I didn't understand that you need the button enabled. I'm currently trying to figure out a solution

Comment: @HelloWorld have you get any event after file upload in your child component?

Answer (score 1):

In your app.component.html :

```
<app-profile-image (mouseenter)=onProfileImageHovered()></app-profile-image>
```

In your app.component.ts :

```
onProfileImageHovered(){
  document.getElementById('fileInput')['disabled'] = false;
  const hoverTextCollection = document.getElementsByClassName('hover-text');
  if (!hoverTextCollection) {
    return null;
  }
  const btn = Array.from(hoverTextCollection).find((e) => {
    return (e instanceof HTMLButtonElement &&
            e.innerHTML === 'Choose file');
  });
  if(btn) {
    btn['disabled'] = false;
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-wrdumr)

Comment: Is it a good way of approach?? Anyhow what will happen if i have 5 or 6 button tags inside the child component?

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use Input property in the child component.
here is the working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-file-upload-preview-ptgq2f
Please accept if the answer works for you.

Comment: I have mentioned in question clearly that i cannot change child component.

Comment: sorry, I missed it. could you please recheck my answer